# Uploading a CSV file and parse it to JSON in REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, papaparse

I am trying to upload a csv file and parse it to Json but couldn't get the parsed ourput.

I tried papaparse but couldn't figure out the problem.

class ImportData extends Component {

```
state = {
    csv: '',
    result: []
}

capture = (e) => {
    this.setState({
       csv: e.target.files[0]
    })
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    Papa.parse(this.state.csv, {
        complete: results => {
            this.setState({
                result: results
            })
        }
    });
}

render(){
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return(

                        <div>
                            <input id="myInput" type="file" onChange= 
                             {this.capture}
                            ref={(ref) => this.myInput = ref} 
                            style={{ display: 'none' }} />




                        </div>
                    {console.log(this.state.csv)}
                    {console.log(this.state.result)}
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </Grid>
    );
}};
```

I am able to see the uploaded file but the problem is i cannot parse it to JSON

Answer (score 0):

take a look at library called [Excelljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs). One stop for everything excel files related.